# Can't log in until after reboot

Tags: macos, password, login

I have an iMac running OS X Mavericks and OS X Server. The OS X Server services running are Time Machine and Xcode.

A couple of times per week, the iMac gets into a state where I cannot log in. I can select my user account on the login screen, and I can enter my password, but the password field just shakes as if I have entered the wrong password. This happens for each of the three user accounts on the machine.

After rebooting, we can log in for a while (a day or two), and then the can't-login state recurs.

I don't know whether this is related, but sometimes this same iMac gets into a state where everything is really slow. Activity Monitor shows that CPU usage is low, memory pressure is low, disk is not full, but everything seems to be running at 5% normal speed. It's fine after a reboot.

When the iMac is in one of those bad states, I can still ssh to it from another Mac, and I can "sudo shutdown -r now" to restart it.

Any ideas about what is going wrong, or how to diagnose the problem?

### Update:

After uninstalling an old version of VirtualBox about a week ago, the problem hasn't recurred.  Maybe its kexts were causing problems?

Comment: Are you logging in to a network user?

Comment: No, logging in as local user.

Comment: What does the log shows?

Comment: I don't see anything in the log that seems relevant.

Comment: → Kristopher: your Update is a correct answer. Both a technic to analyse a problem through elimination and a solution. Next time you'd like to clearly diagnose such a problem, I advise you to `ssh` on the ill Mac and use `kextstat` & `kextunload`.

Answer (score 1):

From your symptoms and the lack of any other any evidence within your
log files,
the origin of your problem is a keyboard mode switch.
This keyboard mode switch will only make your password wrongly typed through the login window and not through an `ssh` access.
This remapping of your keyboard might have been caused by <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (select previous input source) or <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (select next input source).
The 1st one of these 2 key combinations may be easily entered by typing the spacebar on one of its left or right borders, thus pressing the <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> at the same time.
This shortcut is defined in:

```
System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources
```

This keyboard remapping might also have been done by any other keyboard shortcut defined by `Xcode` or another application.

To avoid to be trapped by such an invisible keyboard remapping or misbehaviour, here are 2 personnal trick.

1. Within `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options`,
   for `Display login windows as:`
   select `Name and password`.
   Hence you will have a possibility to diagnose any wrong mapping or any other misbehaviour of your keyboard within the field `Name:`. You might try your password there and have a total feedback.
2. Within `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options`,
   activate the function `Show Input menu in login window`. This 2nd trick won't help you diagnose a dead key.